# I can't bundle app (IOS) - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I use IDE version 6.7(dp4).

I create simple application for iPhone and I have certificate on apple.When I bundle app my screen has freeze.

Here pricture:
[image]

Comment: Since it's a DP release, best to file it as a bug at http://quality.runrev.com/

Comment: There are 2 laptop that I use to build the bundle app. The one can build successful which is the 6.6.1 version but another one cannot do it by using 6.7 version. So, I change to 6.6.1 version but it still like the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be an issue with your certificates, licenses and/or provisioning profiles.
Have you made sure they are set up identically on both machines?
You may need to delete all the certificates and profiles from the second machine and start from scratch....
Also, check out the mailing list archives for others that have had similar problems. There is a wealth of information there:
http://lists.runrev.com/mailman/listinfo/use-livecode